# Polar StereoGraphic projection

Tags: gdalwarp, gdal-translate, gdal-merge

I have two files with the projection information

**Image 1**
'GEOGCS["Moon Spheroid",DATUM["Moon_Spheroid",SPHEROID["Moon Spheroid",1737400,833.3333]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]'

**Image 2**
'PROJCS["Polar StereoGraphic",GEOGCS["Moon Spheroid",DATUM["Moon_Spheroid",SPHEROID["Moon Spheroid",1737400,833.3333]],PRIMEM["Reference_Meridian",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",90],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]'

I am trying to georeference image 1 into Image 2 projection format using gdal utility.

But after several tries, I am unable to do so.

**Here, is the output of my Jupiter notebook.**

```
 File "<ipython-input-31-14f3cc51b5be>", line 4
gdalwarp -t_srs 'EPSG:9001 +datum=Moon_Spheroid' -tr 25 25 -r cubic ch2_sar_ncxl_20191017t234531221_d_sli_xx_fp_hh_d18.tif ch2_sar_ncxl_20191017t234531221_d_sli_xx_fp_hh_d18.tif
                                               ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
How can I fix this?

Comment: Does it make any sense to re-project data from Moon on WGS84 spheroid on Earth?  Maybe it does, I am not familiar with such data.

Comment: It makes sense for Polar data.

Comment: Immediate error comes probably from the syntax. You could try double quotes around -t_srs but your target srs will not work. For example `EPSG:9001` means metre. (note: question edited and my comment about WGS84 is no more valid).

Comment: Thanks, after putting in double-quotes. I am still getting the same error File "<ipython-input-2-287fec552a65>", line 4
    gdalwarp -t_srs "EPSG:9001 +datum=WGS 84" -tr 25 25 -r cubic ch2_sar_ncxl_20191017t234531221_d_sli_xx_fp_hh_d18.tif ch2_sar_ncxl_20191017t234531221_d_sli_xx_fp_hh_d181.tif
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Of course because this parameter `-t_srs "EPSG:9001 +datum=WGS 84"` is plain nonsense.

Comment: Can you please suggest to me how I can then convert my Image 1 into a Polarsterographic map projection?

Comment: You must use a complete and correct projection definition with -t_srs. You can get such for example with `gdalsrsinfo -o proj4 image2.tif`. I am sorry but you must still learn some more basics, for example you seem to use the same filename for input and output in your gdalwarp command and that will fail. If you do not have a teacher to guide you find some GDAL tutorials from the web and follow them before starting to play with your own data.